# Is the integral $\int_0^5 \frac{dx}{(x-3)^{3}} $ divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have an integral that looks like this:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x-3)^{3}}$$ and I know the integral yields $\frac{-1}{2(x-3)^2}$ as the answer.

I agree there is a point of singularity at $x=3$ but if I have to evaluate the integral between the values $x=0$ and $x=5$

$$\int_0^5 \frac{dx}{(x-3)^{3}} =( \frac{-1}{8})-(\frac{-1}{18})=\frac{-5}{72}$$

How is it that my region of integration holds a point that drives the function to $\infty$ and back and still gives me a finite answer.

The professor says that the integral is divergent but how is that I still get a finite answer to this question.

Comment: What you calculated is the principle value.

Comment: You can make sense of the integral as a Cauchy principal value: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0 + } \left( {\int_0^{3 - \varepsilon } {\frac{{dx}}{{(x - 3)^3 }}}  + \int_{3 + \varepsilon }^5 {\frac{{dx}}{{(x - 3)^3 }}} } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0 + } \left( {\frac{1}{{18}} - \frac{1}{{2\varepsilon ^2 }} + \frac{1}{{2\varepsilon ^2 }} - \frac{1}{8}} \right) =  - \frac{5}{{72}}.
$$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: In your case: $\int_0^5 =\int_0^3+\int_3^5$. And boyh integrals in the RHS are divergent. **ADVICE** singularities in integrals, better in the Extrema of the intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that the definite integral you are computing is an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) as the integrand is not continuous on $[0,5]$, and therefore you cannot just compute the anti-derivative of the integrand and evaluate at end points directly.
On the other hand, as
Peter has suggested in the comments, the value you have computed is called the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) or simply principal value.